# C# Getting error when generating tiles from big image

Tags: c#, image-processing

the sample panorama image url https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/360%C2%B0_Hoher_Freschen_Panorama_2.jpg which i saved in my pc and generate tile from that image programmatically and got

> error like out of memory
>
> this line throw the error Bitmap bmLevelSource =
> (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(levelSourceImage);

here is my program code in c# which throw the error

```
   double maxZoom = 5;
    string FILEPATH = @"C:\test\img.jpg";
    string TARGETFOLDER = @"C:\test\Src";
    bool REMOVEXISTINGFILES = true;

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(FILEPATH))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("file not exist");
        return;
    }

    if (maxZoom >= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scale multiplier should be  an integer <=10");
        return;
    }

    //Read image                    
    Bitmap bmSource;
    try
    {
        bmSource = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(FILEPATH);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("image file not valid");
        return;
    }

    //check directory exist
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(TARGETFOLDER))
    {
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(TARGETFOLDER);
    }
    else if (REMOVEXISTINGFILES)
    {
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(TARGETFOLDER);
        foreach (string file in files)
            System.IO.File.Delete(file);

        string[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(TARGETFOLDER);
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
            System.IO.Directory.Delete(dir, true);
    }

    int actualHeight = bmSource.Height;
    int actualWidth = bmSource.Width;

    if (((actualHeight % 256) != 0)
        ||
        ((actualWidth % 256) != 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("image width and height pixels should be multiples of 256");
        return;
    }

    int actualResizeSizeWidth = 1;

    int level = 0;
    while (level <= maxZoom)
    {
        string leveldirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(TARGETFOLDER, String.Format("{0}", level));
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(leveldirectory))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(leveldirectory);

        int rowsInLevel = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, level));
        actualResizeSizeWidth = 256 * rowsInLevel;

        //create image to parse
        int actualResizeSizeHeight = (actualHeight * actualResizeSizeWidth) / actualWidth;
        Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(bmSource, new Size(actualResizeSizeWidth, actualResizeSizeHeight));
        string levelSourceImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(leveldirectory, "level.png");
        resized.Save(levelSourceImage);

        for (int x = 0; x < rowsInLevel; x++)
        {
            string levelrowdirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(leveldirectory, String.Format("{0}", x));
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(levelrowdirectory))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(levelrowdirectory);

            Bitmap bmLevelSource = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(levelSourceImage);

            //generate tiles
            int numberTilesHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(actualResizeSizeHeight / 256.0));
            for (int y = 0; y < numberTilesHeight; y++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Generating Tiles  " + level.ToString() + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString()); int heightToCrop = actualResizeSizeHeight >= 256 ? 256 : actualResizeSizeHeight;
                Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(x * 256, y * 256, 256, heightToCrop);
                //croped
                Bitmap bmTile = bmLevelSource.Clone(destRect, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
                //full tile
                Bitmap bmFullTile = new Bitmap(256, 256);
                Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmFullTile);
                gfx.DrawImageUnscaled(bmTile, 0, 0);
                bmFullTile.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(levelrowdirectory, String.Format("{0}.png", y)));
                bmFullTile.Dispose();
                bmTile.Dispose();
            }
        }
        level++;
    }
```

i comment the below code when i run the program

```
    if (((actualHeight % 256) != 0)
        ||
        ((actualWidth % 256) != 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("image width and height pixels should be multiples of 256");
        return;
    }
```

what is the fault for which i got the error called "Out of Memory"

Thanks

### Edit

actual image height and width was `1250 and 2500`.

```
actualResizeSizeWidth   256
actualResizeSizeHeight  128
```

i include a panorama image url in this post at top. can u plzz download url and execute my code at your end to see memory issue is coming?

### Code Update

i modify the code a bit and dispose some Bitmap.

dispose like this way

```
bmLevelSource.Dispose(); and resized.Dispose();

while (level <= maxZoom)
    {
        string leveldirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(TARGETFOLDER, String.Format("{0}", level));
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(leveldirectory))
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(leveldirectory);

        int rowsInLevel = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Pow(2, level));
        actualResizeSizeWidth = 256 * rowsInLevel;

        //create image to parse
        int actualResizeSizeHeight = (actualHeight * actualResizeSizeWidth) / actualWidth;
        Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(bmSource, new Size(actualResizeSizeWidth, actualResizeSizeHeight));
        string levelSourceImage = System.IO.Path.Combine(leveldirectory, "level.png");
        resized.Save(levelSourceImage);

        for (int x = 0; x < rowsInLevel; x++)
        {
            string levelrowdirectory = System.IO.Path.Combine(leveldirectory, String.Format("{0}", x));
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(levelrowdirectory))
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(levelrowdirectory);

            Bitmap bmLevelSource = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(levelSourceImage);

            //generate tiles
            int numberTilesHeight = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(actualResizeSizeHeight / 256.0));
            for (int y = 0; y < numberTilesHeight; y++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Generating Tiles  " + level.ToString() + " " + x.ToString() + " " + y.ToString()); int heightToCrop = actualResizeSizeHeight >= 256 ? 256 : actualResizeSizeHeight;
                Rectangle destRect = new Rectangle(x * 256, y * 256, 256, heightToCrop);
                //croped
                Bitmap bmTile = bmLevelSource.Clone(destRect, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.DontCare);
                //full tile
                Bitmap bmFullTile = new Bitmap(256, 256);
                Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmFullTile);
                gfx.DrawImageUnscaled(bmTile, 0, 0);
                bmFullTile.Save(System.IO.Path.Combine(levelrowdirectory, String.Format("{0}.png", y)));
                bmFullTile.Dispose();
                bmTile.Dispose();
            }
            bmLevelSource.Dispose();
        }
        level++;
        resized.Dispose();
    }
```

please see my bit modified code and give suggestion now.

Comment: You are very sloppy with your Dispose() calls.  Nothing like Bitmap to remind a programmer that the *using* statement is important.

Comment: please highlight the area in code which need to change.

Comment: looking for suggestion what to do?

Comment: The issue is that you are just manipulating the bitmap without manually managing the memory. Garbage collection in this case might take some time before it empties memory. As @HansPassant suggested, you'd have to spend some time understanding how to carefully (e.g. with the using statement) load and manipulate your bitmap.

Alternatively, if you want fast results for now, you can use a library. I'd recommend the [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/) library.

Then using the library's UnmanagedImage class you should be able to achieve what you want very quickly.

Comment: AForge.NET library can be use to generate tile image?

Comment: i update the code. so now see and tell me does it look good now.